# Trying to remove a char from a string using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to figure out a way to remove a char from a string based on an index value using pointers **and not touching array notation (by which I essentially mean not using any brackets)** at all. As far as I understand *letter = temp should assign what is in temp into the location of letter, but it creates a segmentation fault instead.

```
char *word = "blue";
int length = strlen(word);
int index = 0;

for (index; index < length; index++)
{   
    char *letter = word + index;
    char temp;
    temp = *(letter + 1);
    *letter = temp;
}
    printf("%s\n", word);
```

Edit: Bolded something that the answers seem to be ignoring.

Comment: It does not let you change the string literal. try change to `char word[] = "blue";`

Comment: *Dozens* duplicates related to this question, one well written being : [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Comment: My solution avoids the brackets. Bluepixy would have been correct on any other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put my comments in the code about what is going on

```
    /* normally we would do char word[] = "blue" but that isn't allowed
     * We need to put it on the heap where it can be modified but
     * we can't use array indexing [] so we can do the hack
     * below */

    /* String constants are immutable - they can't be changed
     * so consider them read only. Trying to modify one can
     * lead to undefined behavior including write fault */
    char *constWord = "blue";
    int index = 0;
    int length = strlen(constWord);

    /* Create space on the heap to hold the string + nul terminator */
    char *word = malloc(strlen(constWord + 1));

    /* Copy the string to the heap where it can be modified */
    strcpy(word, constWord);

    for (index; index < length; index++) {
        char *letter = word + index;
        char temp;
        temp = *(letter + 1);
        *letter = temp;
    }

    printf("%s\n", word);

    /* Cleanup */
    free(word);
}
```

Comment: I have no problem saying that this is wrong. If you don't know why, read again your code

Answer (score 0):

`word` is a pointer which is initialized to point to a string constant. The pointer `word` may be modified to point to another string, however if you attempt to modify the string at which `word` is pointing the result is undefined.

Instead you can do `char word[] = "blue"`. Here `word` is an array big enough to hold a word and `\0` following the word. Individual characters within the array can be changed however the address of the array will remain same.